# Limsup of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

I have difficulty proving the following. Let $f_n:[0,1]\to [0,\infty)$ be a sequence of nondecreasing functions. First, how to show that there exists a sequence $x_n\downarrow 0$ such that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}f_n(x_n)=\lim_{x\to 0}\limsup_{n\to\infty}f_n(x).$$

How to show then that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\limsup_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$$ if and only if
$$f_n(x_n)\to 0$$ for every sequence $x_n\to 0$?

Comment: For $x \in [0,1]$, define $H(x) = \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x)$.  You will first need to prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} H(x)$ exists (possibly being $\infty$).  Can you do that step?

Comment: Let me know if you need more help after you demonstrate you can take that limit of $H(x)$.  In general, it is best to show your thoughts and preliminary work.  An interesting feature of this problem, it seems to me, is that you can construct your $x_n$ values _themselves_ only over some sparse subsequence of indices $n[k]$, rather than over all natural numbers $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.  So, define $x_{n[k]}$ over some convenient subsequence $n[k]$, and then fill in the remaining $x_i$ values arbitrarily, say, keep them constant between $n[k]$ indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For $x \in [0,1]$ define 
$$H(x) = \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x)$$ 
It is not difficult to show that $H(x)$ is a nondecreasing (and possibly infinite valued) function over $x\in [0,1]$. It follows that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} H(x)$ exists (possibly being $\infty$).

2) Fix $x>0$. Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be *any* sequence of real numbers in $[0,1]$ that satisfies $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n = 0$.  Then there is an integer $m$ such that
$$0\leq x_n \leq x \quad,  \forall n \geq m$$
From this (and the fact that each $f_n$ function is nondecreasing) it is easy to prove 
$$ \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x_n) \leq \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} H(x) $$

3) We prove *there exists* a particular sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for which the following reverse inequality holds: 
$$ \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x_n) \geq \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} H(x) $$

For simplicity assume that $H(1)<\infty$, and so $H(1/k)<\infty$ for all $k\in\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ (the general result is similar).

- Define integer $n[1]>0$ such that $f_{n[1]}(1) \geq H(1) - 1$.
- For $k \in \{2, 3, 4, ...\}$, define integer $n[k]>n[k-1]$ such that $f_{n[k]}(1/k) \geq H(1/k) - 1/k$.

Now consider a subsequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $x_{n[k]} = 1/k$ for each $k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$, and the in-between values are held constant.

Comment: I am (accidentally) looking at this question from 2 years ago, the asker never bothered to respond to my hints.  I think sufficient time has passed so that I am not giving away any homework answer.